# Как правильно создать условие у select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! При выборе `<option value="1">Россия</option>` блок `.block` скрывается, а блок `.block-rus` становится доступным. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать условие, при котором при выборе любого другого `option`, кроме `<option value="1">Россия</option>` наоборот блок `.block` становился бы доступным, а блок `.block-rus` скрывался, а при выборе `<option value="0"></option>` скрывались оба блока? Спасибо!

```js
$("#category").change(function(){
   var v = $(this).val();
   $(".block").toggle(v != 1);
   $(".block-rus").toggle(v == 1);
});
```

```css
.block,
.block-rus {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-placeholder="" name="catlist[]" id="category" onchange="onCategoryChange(this)">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Россия</option>
  <option value="2">Украина</option>
  <option value="3">Белоруссия</option>
</select>
<div class="block">Выбрана другая страна</div>
<div class="block-rus">Выбрана Россия</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#category").change(function(){
   var v = $(this).val();
   switch (v) {
     case "0":
       $(".block").hide();
       $(".block-rus").hide();
       break;
     case "1":
       $(".block").hide();
       $(".block-rus").show();
       break;
     default:
       $(".block").show();
       $(".block-rus").hide();
       break;
    }
});
```

```css
.block,
.block-rus {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-placeholder="" name="catlist[]" id="category" >
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">Россия</option>
  <option value="2">Украина</option>
  <option value="3">Белоруссия</option>
</select>
<div class="block">Выбрана другая страна</div>
<div class="block-rus">Выбрана Россия</div>
```